# replacing 2D matrix values with red or black pixels

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy, python-imaging-library

i have a big 2D matrix containing values 0, 200 and 500 , i need to replace 200 with red pixels and 500 with black pixels an 0 with white pixels

Comment: How do you expect this to look? How are you trying to display this? Please add somethings you've tried - we can't do it all for you

Comment: A 2d matrix i can be viewed as a image,using various methods, but not as color image. So to highlight those matrix shells containing 200 and 500 , i have to put color in those particular shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be difficult to do it.
I am assuming the array which you have is a numpy array.
I used python3 for this below.
Hope this helps.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

#----------- (Your Array of 500s, 200s and 0s)------------
a = np.random.randint(3, size=(500, 500))
a[a==2] = 500
a[a==1] = 200
# --------------------------------------------------------

# ----------- Code which you need to run ----------------------------
R, G, B = np.zeros(a.shape), np.zeros(a.shape), np.zeros(a.shape)
R[a==200], G[a==200], B[a==200] = 255, 0, 0
R[a==500], G[a==500], B[a==500] = 0, 0, 0
R[a==0], G[a==0], B[a==0] = 255, 255, 255
R, G, B = Image.fromarray(R.astype('uint8'),mode=None), Image.fromarray(G.astype('uint8'),mode=None), Image.fromarray(B.astype('uint8'),mode=None) 
merged=Image.merge("RGB",(R,G,B))

merged.show()
# ------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: Output of the above code]